# How to sort duplicate element based on index position in javascript

Tags: javascript

Input  :

```
arr[] = [3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5]
```

After sorting array by, 
array as shown below

```
[1(8), 2(4), 3(0), 3(2), 3(5), 3(7), 4(1), 4(6), 5(3), 5(9)]
```

Comment: The expected output is invalid. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the values with the index. Then `sort`, and finally `map` to the desire string:

```js
var arr = [3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5];

console.log(arr
   .map((x, i) => [x, i])
   .sort((a, b) =>  a[0] - b[0])
   .map(x => `${x[0]}(${x[1]})`));
```

Comment: Just `sort` isn't enough, try adding `10` to the array.

Comment: @georg, good point! I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const a = [3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5]
const result =a.map((el, i) => ({ index: i, value: el }))
.sort( (a, b) => a.value - b.value)
.map(({index,value})=>` ${value}(${index})`);

console.log(result)
```